# Recovering Kubernetes cluster without certs

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have the following scenario in the lab and would like to see if its possible to recover. The cluster is broken but very expected since I was testing how far I could go with breaking the cluster and still be able to recover.

Env:
Kubernetes 1.16.3
Kubespray

I was experimenting a bit and don't have any data on this cluster but I am still very curious if it's possible to recover. I have a healthy 3 node etcd cluster with the original configuration (all namespaces, workloads, configmaps etc). I don't have the original SSL certs for the control plane.

I removed all nodes from the cluster (kubeadm reset). I have original manifests and kubelet config and try to re-init master nodes. It is quite more successful than I thought it would be but not where I want it to be.
After successful kubeadm init, the kubelet and control plane containers start successfully but the corresponding pods are not created. I am able to use the kube API with kubectl and see the nodes, namespaces, deployments, etc.

In the kube-system namespace all daemonsets still exist but the pods won't start with the following message:

```
49m         Warning   FailedCreate        daemonset/kube-proxy                                Error creating: Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout
```

The kubelet logs the following re control plane pods

```
Jul 21 22:30:02 k8s-master-4 kubelet[13791]: E0721 22:30:02.088787   13791 kubelet.go:1664] Failed creating a mirror pod for "kube-scheduler-k8s-master-4_kube-system(3e128801ef687b022f6c8ae175c9c56d)": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout
Jul 21 22:30:53 k8s-master-4 kubelet[13791]: E0721 22:30:53.089517   13791 kubelet.go:1664] Failed creating a mirror pod for "kube-controller-manager-k8s-master-4_kube-system(da5cfae13814fa171a320ce0605de98f)": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout
```

During kubeadm reset/init process I already have some steps so I can get to where I am now (delete serviceaccounts to reset the tokens, delete some configmaps (kuebadm etc))

My question is - is it possible to recover the control plane without the certs. And if its complicated but still possible process I would still like to know.

All help appreciated

Henro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to recover the control plane without the certs.

Yes, should be able to. The certs  are required but they don't have to be the very same ones that you created the cluster initially with. All the [certificates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/) including the [CA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/manual-rotation-of-ca-certificates/) can be rotated across the board. The kubelet even supports [certificate auto-rotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/). The configurations need to match everywhere though. Meaning the CA needs to be the same that created the CSRs and cert keys/certs need to be created from the same CSRs.

Also, all the components need to use the same CA and be able to authenticate with the API server (kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, etc) . I'm not entirely sure about the logs that you are seeing but it looks like the kube-controller-manager and kube-scheduler are not able to authenticate and join the cluster. So I would take a look at their cert configurations:

- `/etc/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.conf`
- `/etc/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.conf`

Also, you would find every PKI component that you need to verify under `/etc/kubernetes/pki`

✌️

Comment: Thanks Rico! One interesting fact that i forgot to mention was that I was getting the same error for apiserver pod but after a few days the pod was eventually created. I am looking at the cert config for scheduler and controller manager,  but I think these are new already, and created by kube adm in one of the init phases. I am thinking that there must be some more cert config inside the the cluster for  pods and controllers.

Comment: I have some good news here. The cluster is still partially broken but the control plane pods (including kube-proxy, calico, dns pods) are now up and running. I found this https://success.docker.com/article/unable-to-deploy-application-in-kubernetes but was not sure how would it relate to my case. I had three mutating webhooks and deleted them all. Once i deleted them, the pods were created and started to be scheduled.

Comment: at this point its just a couple of applications like prometheus or cert-manager all mainly because of authentication. i believe this can easily be fixed. I was also able to add bunch of new master and worker nodes.  I will have to do some reading on the webhooks to better understand how would they prevent creation of control plane pods.

Comment: all fixed now. the control plane redeployed and all apps working.

Comment: awesome, great to hear!